# How to simplify usage of overloaded subscript operator via pointer?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript

I have a class `Foo` that encapsulates access to a vector and provides access to it via the subscript operator:

```
typedef int* IntPtr; 

class Foo {
   std::vector<IntPtr> bars;
   IntPtr& operator[](size_t idx) {
      return bars[idx];
   }
};
```

In class `Bar` i want to use `Foo`. While solution 1 works, it is rather inconvenient. I would prefer something like solution 2. Obviously, a method call (even if it returns an lvalue) can't be assigned something, albeit the method call doesn't do anything else than  solution 1.

```
class Bar {
   Foo *foo; //some initialization

   IntPtr helper(size_t idx) {
      return (*foo)[idx];
   }

   void barfoo() {
      size_t baz = 1;
      IntPtr qux;

      //solution 1
      qux = (*foo)[baz];  //works
      (*foo)[baz] = &1;    //works

      //solution 2
      qux = helper(baz);  //works
      helper(baz) = &1;    //does not work: "expression is not assignable"
   }     
};
```

**Question:** How can I simplify the usage of an overloaded subscript operator?

**EDIT:** Changed used type to from `int` to `int*`. Sorry, I screwed up when creating the example.

I guess the problem is because of the twisted `int*&`.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/cIfszt) (once I fix the accessibility of `Foo::operator[]`). You certainly can assign to an *lvalue* reference returned by a function. Are you sure the error comes from that code?

Comment: if helper returns a reference your solution 2 works

Comment: What compiler are you using? Because that line should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to write a regular method, e.g `Foo::at(size_t idx)`, providing the same functionality as your operator.
Notice that the STL does the same (just take a look at `std::vector`).
You can then simply call `foo->at(baz);`. To avoid rendundancy you could change the implementation of `operator[]`:

```
int& operator[](size_t idx) {
    return at(idx);
}
```

In your snippet, you cant assign a value to the return because you have forgotten to return a reference.

Not that nice but an alternative would be `foo->operator[](baz);` though I strongly discourage you to write such an ugly code.

Comment: Even then `foo->at(baz) = 1` would not be possible.

Comment: @mort Why not? It should be.

Comment: Eh? Why not? `at` is a regular method, you can call it just like every other method. You call a method from a pointer with the `->` operator.

Comment: Well, the STL defines both `operator[]` and `at()` because they have entirely different semantics: `at()` does bounds checking, `operator[]` does not. If it were not for this semantic difference, having both functions would simply be code bloat, i. e. something that should not be done.

Comment: Found the mistake (see my answer). I upvoted your answer (it lead me the right way...) but don't want to accept it, as it is not actually the right one. If you edit it, I'll happily reward you by accepting it :)

Comment: Is that fine this way?

Answer (score 0):

Darn. I just forgot to let `helper` return the value via a reference:

```
IntPtr& helper(size_t idx)
```

or

```
int*& helper(size_t idx)
```